# Placement new in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I need to find a workaround for a bug with placement new in g++. I now it was fixed in gcc-4.3 but I have to support versions 4.2 and 4.1. For example, following code compiles with an error

**"error: no matching function for call to 'operator new(long unsigned int, void*&)"**

```
template<class T, template<typename> class Alloc> 
inline void* type_ctor()
{
    Alloc<T> a; void* p = a.allocate(1);
    new(p) T;
    return p;
}

.....

type_ctor<A, NewAllocator >();
```

Comment: I'm interested. Which bug in gcc-4.3 do you think has 'fixed' this issue? I definitely get this error (as expected) in gcc-4.4 when I don't `#include <new>` .

Comment: Could be that earlier some common standard header included `<new>` and now it doesn't?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use the standard library placement `new`s, you have to `#include <new>`.